# Redirecting laravel default registration to previous url or page

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

i changed my registrationController middleware to auth:SuperAdmin guard to be visited  by admins only. However after the admin registers a new user it redirects them to the login page. And with the code below it redirects to the admin login page when i want it to redirect back to the admin dashboard as the admin is already logged in.

#### My registrationController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected function redirectTo()
{
    /* generate URL dynamicaly */
    return '/path'; // return dynamicaly generated URL.
}

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:SuperAdmin');
    }
    
    

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'alpha', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
       
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    
}
```

#### Tried this and it redirects to the adminLogin page

```
  protected function create(array $data)
{
    $this->redirectTo = '/admin';
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Try to find other controllers under the same folder with `registrationController`, there will also have some redirect properties and methods, modify them and see if this works for you.

Comment: am using the default or standard registration and i cant seem to find other redirect properties in the folder other than for things like verify email, reset password and so on

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it was redirecting me to the login page was because of this line "$this->guard()->login($user);"  in the  "public function register(Request $request)" in registeredUsers which is found in the vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/registerUsers.
what i did is overwrite the register function by excluding ""$this->guard()->login($user);" through the registerController and the registered function as well with my custom route.

#### RegisterController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    
    
    

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:SuperAdmin');
    }
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 201)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
    
    
    

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'alpha', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
   
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard')->with('msg', 'The Message');
    }
    
}
```